# Zero Initialize a Type

Tags: c++, default-constructor, decltype, temporary, declval

Given a variable of an unsigned integral type: `foo` lets say I want to do this:

```
const decltype<foo> bar{};

cout << (55834574890LL & ~bar) << endl;
```

That gives me the expected 42. But now let's say that I want to do away with the `bar` variable. So something like this:

```
cout << (55834574890LL & ~decltype<foo>{}) << endl;
```

But I just get an error:

> error: expected primary-expression before `decltype`

I've also tried `declval` but that returns a reference, which is also no good. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: `decltype<foo> bar{}` is this syntax valid? You probably meant `decltype(foo) bar{}`

Comment: What compiler are you using?  `const decltype<foo> bar{};` should not compile: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48d19c6ef9ec5907

Comment: @LakshayGarg Arg you're right :(

Comment: @NathanOliver Arg you're right :(

Comment: Was it a good idea to edit the original mistake out of the question?  Surely this will just confuse anyone reading it for the first time.

Comment: @PaulSanders Yeah I guess you're right I've rolled that back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use round brackets:

```
auto v = 55834574890LL & ~decltype(foo){};
```

[Here's a demo.](https://godbolt.org/g/zLGTR9)